# Use Haskell like Prelude modules in a module in raku

Tags: haskell, raku

I'm writing a drawing package with some parts, and I have operators and data types scattered througout. However I don't want the users to add the corresponding modules every time, since it would be quite messy, for instance I'd have a `Point` class, a `Monoid` role and a `Style` class
in different paths like this

```perl
unit module Package::Data::Monoid;
# $?FILE = lib/Package/Data/Monoid.pm6

role Monoid {...}
```

```perl
unit module Package::Data::Point;
# $?FILE = lib/Package/Data/Point.pm6

class Point {...}
```

```perl
unit module Package::Data::Style;
# $?FILE = lib/Package/Data/Style.pm6

class Style {...}
```

I would like to have a `haskell` like prelude in `lib/Package/Prelude.pm6`
with the effect that I can write such scripts

```perl
use Package::Prelude;

# I can use Point right away, Style etc...
```

instead of doing

```perl
use Package::Data::Style;
use Package::Data::Point;
use Package::Data::Monoid;

# I can too use point right away, but for users not knowing the
# inner workings it's too overwhelming
```

I've tried many things:

- This version doesn't give me the right effect, I have to type
  the whole path to point, i.e., `Package::Data::Point`...

```perl
unit module Package::Prelude;
# $?FILE = lib/Package/Prelude.pm6
use Package::Data::Style;
use Package::Data::Point;
use Package::Data::Monoid;
```

- This version gives me the `Point` right away, but I get
  problems with the operators and so on, also I would just like to
  add automatically everything from the exported routines in the mentioned
  example packages.

```perl
# $?FILE = lib/Package/Prelude.pm6
use Package::Data::Style;
use Package::Data::Point;
use Package::Data::Monoid;

sub EXPORT {
  hash <Point> => Point
     , <Style> => Style
     , <mappend> => &mappend
     ...
}
```

Do you people know a better and quick way of getting such a prelude-like
file?

Comment: You can use `unit class Package::Data::Point`. You don't have to use `module`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `EXPORT` is in the right direction. The key things to know are:

- Imports are lexical
- We can use introspection to obtain and access the symbols in the current lexical scope

So the recipe is:

- `use` all the modules inside of `EXPORT`
- Then extract all the imported symbols and return them as the result from `EXPORT`

As an example, I create a module `Foo::Point`, including an operator and a class:

```raku
unit module Foo::Point;

class Point is export {
    has ($.x, $.y);
}

multi infix:<+>(Point $a, Point $b) is export {
    Point.new(x => $a.x + $b.x, y => $a.y + $b.y)
}
```

And, just to demonstrate it can work with multiple modules, also a `Foo::Monad`:

```raku
unit module Foo::Monad;

class Monad is export {
    method explain() { say "Just think of a burrito..." }
}
```

The goal is to make this work:

```raku
use Foo::Prelude;
say Point.new(x => 2, y => 4) + Point.new(x => 3, y => 5);
Monad.explain;
```

Which can be achieved by writing a `Foo::Prelude` that contains:

```raku
sub EXPORT() {
    {
        use Foo::Point;
        use Foo::Monad;
        return ::.pairs.grep(*.key ne '$_').Map;
    }
}
```

There's a few oddities in here to explain:

1. A `sub` has implicit declarations of `$_`, `$/`, and `$!`. Exporting these would result in a compile-time symbol clash error when the module is `use`'d. A block only has an implicit `$_`. Thus we make our life easier with a nested bare block.
2. The `grep` is to make sure we don't export our implicitly declared `$_` symbol  (thanks to the nested block, it's the only one we have to care about).
3. `::` is a way to reference the current scope (etymology: `::` is the package separator). `::.pairs` thus obtains `Pair` objects for each symbol in the current scope.

There's a speculated re-export mechanism that may appear in a future Raku language release that would eliminate the need for this bit of boilerplate.

Comment: Finally, this is exactly the behaviour I was looking for, thanks so much!

Comment: I don't think this approach works if the re-exported modules export an operator sub, I get an "Cannot import symbol '%?LANG' from 'Project::Prelude', because it already exists in this lexical scope.". If I remove the exported operator from the prelude it works.

Comment: NB If you use `unit ... Foo::Prelude;` in the `Foo::Prelude` package, the `sub EXPORT ...` must appear *before* the `unit` line. See the ***Importing* symbols into a package and then *re-exporting* them** section (and its footnotes) in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69017360/separating-operator-definitions-for-a-class-to-other-files-and-using-them/69018308#69018308) for more discussion.