# Making exported functions in submodules accessible in global namespace in Raku

Tags: function, module, raku, rakudo

I created a minimal working module called `new`. The folder structure, [link here](https://bitbucket.org/sumankhanal/new/src/master/) is as follows:

```
new
│   .gitignore
│   Changes
│   dist.ini
│   LICENSE
│   META6.json
│   README.md
│
├───lib
│   │   new.rakumod
│   │
│   ├───Desc
│   │       Mean.rakumod
│   │
│   └───Deviation
│           DeviationMean.rakumod
│
└───t
        01-basic.rakutest
```

I have two functions, `mean` in `Desc::Mean.rakumod` and `deviation_from_mean` in `Deviation::DeviationMean.rakumod` modules in `lib`.
These are simple functions, I don't want to have any namespace defined for them. So when I install this module, and try to use this module with `use new`, I want to be able to access these two functions without calling their sub-module names.

What I want to do is (which does not work now)

```
use new;

my @test1 = [6,6,4,6,8,6,8,4,4,6,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,4,4,8,8,8,8,4,4,4,8,6,8,4];
say mean(@test1);
say deviation_from_mean(@test1);
```

instead of (which works)

```
use new;
use Desc::Mean;
use Deviation::DeviationMean;

my @test1 = [6,6,4,6,8,6,8,4,4,6,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,4,4,8,8,8,8,4,4,4,8,6,8,4];
say mean(@test1);
say deviation_from_mean(@test1);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# main.raku
use lib 'lib';
use new;
say mean; # 42

# Desc::Mean
unit module Desc::Mean;
sub mean is export { 42 }

# new
sub EXPORT {
  {
    use Desc::Mean;
    return ::.pairs.grep(*.key ne '$_').Map;
  }
}
unit module new;
```

Notes:

- The [`sub EXPORT { ... }`](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules#EXPORT) in the `new` module must come *before* the `unit module new;` statement.
- `use` further modules (eg `Deviation::DeviationMean`) as desired in the `EXPORT` sub to *import* those module's symbols into the `new` compunit; the `return ::.pairs.grep(*.key ne '$_').Map;` will then *re-export* all their symbols to whatever `use`s `new`.

For an explanation of the above see:

- [jnthn's answer to **Use Haskell like Prelude modules in a module**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61179929/1077672).
- The "***Importing* symbols** into a package and **then *re-exporting* them**" section of [my answer to **Separating operator definitions for a class to other files and using them**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69018308/1077672).

Answer (score 5):

Roughly speaking & following the [docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules#Exporting_and_selective_importing) you can put these method names as exports into the `new` namespace like this (in new.rakumod):

```
my package EXPORT::DEFAULT {
    OUR::mean := "Desc::Mean::mean";
    OUR::deviation_from_mean :=
         "Deviation::DeviationMean::deviation_from_mean";
}
```

Comment: @raiph - I can see that the referred prior question has a good answer - but its title is very obscure - if you reinstate this one and refer to it, then IMO there is a much bigger change that searchers will find their answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61179586/use-haskell-like-prelude-modules-in-a-module-in-raku

Comment: I too thought the title was obscure. Last I knew marking a Q as a duplicate didn't remove a Q from either SO's or Google's search indexes and thus didn't  impact searching. And I'm presuming it still doesn't and won't in the future. But I hear you, and see someone has upvoted. So I went ahead and re-opened. I was expecting SO to keep the duplicate mark too. (Per a meta post I had read.) But SO removed the duplicate marking! :( Sigh. Anyhoo, I decided to resolve that problem by writing another answer here that referred to jnthn's, as you suggested. Hth.